# Being informed when a zoomToRect: animation completes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

In the iPhone 3.0 SDK, how can I be informed when a `zoomToRect:animated:` animation completes?

Sometimes the scrollview doesn't zoom at all (if it's already at the proper zoom level), and there doesn't seem to be a way to detect that.

Comment: Just a question: if it doesn't actually zoom do you need notified?

Comment: Yes, I need a way to figure out either case.

Comment: Are you calling zoomToRect:.... with the exact same rect that's currently showing, or are you saying that you're zooming in on a _different_ rect, but at the same scale?

Comment: If my solution is the one you ended up using, I'd appreciate you selecting me as the correct answer.

Comment: Wil Shipley: different rect, same scale, and it doesn't scroll to it. You have to call both zoom and scroll, apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your delegate, you can listen for `- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale`

see [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:)

Comment: You shouldn't be calling zoomToRect if you don't have to zoom.  Use the zooming, zoomBouncing, and zoomScale properties of your scrollview to detect that

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably to put in a check before starting the animation.  If the zoom level is already correct, call [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod) withObject:id waitUntilDone:NO].

You won't be able to use the same method as scrollViewDidEndZooming, because you can only pass one argument, but it will trigger an asynchronous call on the main thread